# MSVC2015 decltype parameter type in overloaded template function

Tags: c++, c++11

Is the following program compliant C++11? If so, do you know of a specific MSVC bug that triggers it? and/or a possible work-around?

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {};
struct B {};

constexpr A aaa = {};
constexpr B bbb = {};

template <typename T>
void foo(T, decltype(aaa)) { std::cout << "a"; }

template <typename T>
void foo(T, decltype(bbb)) { std::cout << "b"; }
// ^ C2995 'void foo(T,unknown-type)': function template has already been defined

int main()
{
    foo(0, aaa);
    foo(0, bbb);
}
```

If  the actual types are substituted for `decltype` then it works, but in practice these types are too complicated to reproduce and I'd prefer not to have aliases for them.

Comment: Compile fine with gcc/clang, and I don't see stuff not c++11 compliant neither.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Works for me (VS 2015 / v140) with the following minor modification:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {};
struct B {};

constexpr A aaa = {};
constexpr B bbb = {};

using A_type = decltype(aaa);
using B_type = decltype(bbb);

template <typename T>
void foo(T, A_type) { std::cout << "a"; }

template <typename T>
void foo(T, B_type) { std::cout << "b"; }

int main()
{
    foo(0, aaa);
    foo(0, bbb);
}
```

But this variant yields the same error (not sure what to make of it):

```
template <typename T>
struct TypeWrapper {
    using type = T;
};

template <typename T>
void foo(T, typename TypeWrapper<decltype(aaa)>::type) { std::cout << "a"; }

template <typename T>
void foo(T, typename TypeWrapper<decltype(bbb)>::type) { std::cout << "b"; }
```

Comment: I thought MSVC was doing textual replacement of aliases. I'm surprised that it's working. I was dealing with some nasty bug not a long time ago related to these `unknown-type`, good to know that aliases are working.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot: Type alias is not considered a new separate type, right? I would rather expect it not to work myself, now that you brought it up. Apparently, it's not the type itself that confuses the compiler but `decltype()` construct, and my modification puts it in a different context where the compiler _can_ process it correctly. At least that's my current theory.

Comment: Apparently this works too: `template<typename T> using wrap = T;` then put `wrap<decltype(aaa)>` in the parameter list.

Comment: @RossBencina: good one, I forgot you can do template typedefs like that now. It's odd that my wrapper didn't work, then...

Comment: @VioletGiraffe Indeed, type aliases don't introduce new types, but the way MSVC parser is working, making it separate must clear some states or maybe forcing it to find the type before the function declaration, making things work.